# Am not sure how to handle the default in switch?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var getfiles = new fileshare.Program();

        string realname = "*test*";
        string Location = "SVR01";
        foreach (var file in getfiles.GetFileList(realname,Location))
        {getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName); }

        }
    private FileInfo[] GetFileList(string pattern,string Location)
    {

        try
        {
            switch (Location)
            {
                case "SVR01":
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\SVR01\Dev");
                        return di.GetFiles(pattern);
                    }
                case "SVR02":
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\SVR02\Dev");
                        return di.GetFiles(pattern);
                    }
                case "SVR03":
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\SVR03\Prod");
                        return di.GetFiles(pattern);
                    }
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        return null;
        }

    }
    private void copytolocal(string filename)
    {
        string nameonly = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        File.Copy(filename,Path.Combine(@"c:\",nameonly),true);

    }
    }
```

Am handle the default switch statement but not sure am doing right,some one please correct me .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the `default` clause.  What do you want to do?

Comment: I suspect your immediate problem is that you're returning `null`, and then trying to enumerate over that. Suggest a different implementation whereby you predefine those locations as Anastasiosyal suggests.

Comment: @SLaks,if no location matched then i will stop the process or simply say i will throw catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should throw an exception only in cases where you don't expect something to happen. If a directory other than SRV01/02/03 is not expected, throwing exception could be fine. If you expect it to happen and want to handle it gracefully, don't throw an exception.

But catching the exception you just threw and writing it to the console in the same function doesn't make sense. You kill all the purpose of throwing an exception there. If you want to write an error to the console, you can do that directly in the default statement.

If you want to handle the case when `GetFiles` throws an exception, handle it specifically. Catching an exception and writing it to console does not make sense. If you catch it, it means that you know what to do with it. If you don't, don't catch it.

Say your network is dead and `GetFiles` raises `IOException`. You catch it and return null and your code will raise `NullReferenceException`. Because of that, you lose the information about why that exception is raised.

What do you want to do if network connection is lost? You want to exit? Then you don't need to do anything, an unhandled exception already does that for you. You need to continue running? Are you sure? If app exits successfully will it mean "it has completed everything it's supposed to do" or "there could have been problems but you don't care"? If you're sure it's ok to "ignore" the error, then catch the exception, inform and continue, it's fine. Just make sure of your intent. Exceptions aren't bad or evil. They are there because they are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you simply need to check if a location is in a list of allowed locations. I don't think a switch is a good candidate for something like this. It looks more like configuration, maybe something along the following lines would allow you to read such values from a configuration file for example. Also the logic in each switch statement is the same, so if we can minimise this repetition, it's a bonus

```
private List<string> _allowedLocations

public YourClassConstructor()
{
   _allowedLocations = new List() 
   {@"\\SVR01\Dev", @"\\SVR02\Dev", @"\\SVR02\Dev"}
}

private FileInfo[] GetFileList(string pattern,string location)
{
   if (location == null) 
      throw new ArgumentNullException("location");

   if (!_allowedLocations.Contains(location))
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("location");

   var di = new DirectoryInfo(location);
   return di.GetFiles(pattern);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default in a switch statement is basically a catch all (or what youre doing in your catch statement). If something lands in your switch statement and hits the default, it may as well gone to your catch. My suggestion, return a null and write to the console whatever your exception is. If your exception works, keep it as is. Like @SLaks said, you can do whatever you want in your default clause, because it is the switches form of a catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for an internal environment where you have full control of the network paths, then you have the option to make an enum for location, which would give you the advantage of each possibility showing up in Intellisense.  I additionally agree with what Kevin pointed out, in that you are throwing the exception only to catch it yourself within the same method (an antipattern).  The enum is my only suggestion, otherwise your understanding and implementation of default is correct (i.e., to catch all unexpected/invalid cases).